# How to clear the enter buffer in C++

Tags: c++, windows-console

So I have a menu that uses arrow keys to navigate on the options, The thing is when I chose an option using enter key, the function gets called but it does not go back to the menu but rather calls the function again.
Here is my code

```
int menu(){
 string Menu[6] = {"Insert Student Record", "Delete Student Record", "Update Student Record", "Display All Student Record", "Exit & Save"};
 int pointer = 0;
 HANDLE  hConsole;
 hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

 while(true){
    system("cls");
    SetColor(11);cout<<"\n\tPlease navigate to the menu using up-down arrow keys"<<endl;SetColor(15);
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){
        if(i==pointer){
             SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 159);
             cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }else{
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15); 
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15);

     }
    
     while(true){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0){
            --pointer;
            if(pointer == -1){
                pointer = 4;
            }
            break;
        }else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0){
            ++pointer;
            if(pointer == 5){
                pointer = 0;
            }
            break;
        }else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0){
            switch(pointer){
            case 0:
            {
                system("cls");
                insertMode();
            }break;
            case 1:
            {
                system("cls");
                deleteMode();
            }break;
            case 2:
            {
                system("cls");
                updateMode();
                cout<<"\n\t";
            }break;
            case 3:
            {
                system("cls");
                studList.display();
                cout<<"\n\t";system("pause");
            }break;
            case 4:
            {
                system("cls");
                exitMessage();
                studList.save();
                exit(0);
            } break;
          }
          break;
        }
     }
      Sleep(150);
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: I just had a look at the doc.: [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate). Please, note: _If the most significant bit is set, the key is down_ I assume you receive the `VK_RETURN` twice, once for pressing and once for releasing. Instead of checking for `!= 0`, you could check `if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000)`. (Take it with a grain of salt. I didn't test it nor I'm an expert in Windows API programming.)

Comment: If the above hint doesn't work as expected, the other option could be `if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x01)` to detect key presses. (I'm afraid that the most significant bit is returned as long as the key is pressed. Sorry, I'm really no Win API expert.) ;-)